# Displaying multiple errors (one per line) in asp-validation-for

Tags: asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core 3.1

I have the following code in my View:

```
<span asp-validation-for="NewPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
```

If I type in a password, such as 'a', I get multiple errors back.  I want to display them in that span **ONE** **PER** **LINE**.

In my Controller I have the following:

```
var descriptions = string.Empty;

foreach (var error in errors)
    descriptions += error.Description + "<br />";

ModelState.AddModelError("NewPassword", descriptions);
```

But this does not translate the "br" tags and they get displayed as if they were part of one very long single error message.

**Note**:  Adding them one at a time into the ModelState simply overwrites the previous, leaving only the last one displayed.

Instead of "br", i've tried HTMLString.NewLine and Environment.NewLine but none of these work.  I could write a loop in my View, but is there a preferred way in ASP.NET Core?

So my question is:  How can I put a new line between each description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Instead of "br", i've tried HTMLString.NewLine and Environment.NewLine but none of these work.

1. That's because `<br/>` will be escaped by default. If you wish, you could use `@Html.Raw()` to generate the raw content without escaping the dangerous characters. But I don't think it's a good idea: there will be a high risk of XSS if you output a raw string directly.
2. By default, `\r\n` won't be displayed in browser. You need a CSS snippet to show a new line.

A much better way is to use the CSS to control the display style:  add a style for the validation field in your `*.css` file:

```css
span.field-validation-error{
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

And change the csharp code to use a `\n` as separator:

```cs
foreach (var error in errors)
    descriptions += error.Description + "\n";
```

**Demo** :

[image]

Comment: Mate, that works thank you.  I've searched the web and found some 'horrible' solutions, but yours is neat and concise.  It  will be marked as answer.  I do understand why <br /> would not work, as you would be able to inject <script> etc.